# Classroom enhancement resources for linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, education

My university offers small grants (in the \$100 - \$300 range) for classroom enhancement resources.  In the past, I've applied for and received a grant to purchase a Zometools kit used for constructing models of basic three-dimensional polytopes which can be used in an Abstract Algebra course to help students study finite subgroups of the orthogonal group of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Next semester, I will be teaching Linear Algebra and I am interested if anyone has suggestions for items that would enhance students' learning of the subject.  Ideally, I'd like any item I purchase to be sustainable (i.e. capable of being used in other semesters by other instructors).

Comment: Hey Professor, not sure if you ever got those resources, but you did a great job teaching the Linear Algebra course and especially the Real Analysis course the semester after. Thanks for that!